# Arduino IDE on Ubuntu 22.04.1 can't see a Wemos D1 Mini (CP210x)

Tags: arduino

I have a new laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I installed the Arduino IDE 1.18.19.
The IDE port settings finds an Arduino Uno (CH340 driver) with no problem. But it doesn't see the Wemos D1 Mini (CP210x driver).

```
modinfo cp210x
```

Returns lots of data, telling me that the driver is loaded.

Any ideas?